# (Unity) Enum-alternative for MonoBehaviour scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine, enums

I hope it's okay to ask in this forum, otherwise I hope you can point me in the right direction.

I'm developing an app which contains four mini-games inside. From the main-menu you can select which game, and then the desired game mode and finally the difficulty. The games, game modes and difficulties are selected via a UIButton.

Every mini-game has around four different game-modes, and some of the game modes are represented in multiple games. Like, GameOne has these game-modes (1, 2, 3, 4), GameTwo has maybe: (1, 2, 3, 5), and GameThree (1, 2, 5, 6)

Normally I'd make a method with an enum-param for when selecting the game-mode and difficulty, but since enums aren't really possible to select with MonoBehaviour-scripts I'm feeling a little lost on a work-around.

Would you recommend just creating a class for each game selection, and inside that class have multiple methods and call them individually from each UIButton like this:

```
 public class GameOne : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
    public void SelectGameModeOne()
    {
 
    }
 
     public void selectGameModeTwo()
     {
 
     }
 
 }
```

.. or is there another fancy way of doing this?

I could go with integers instead of enums, but as my application scales, with my memory, I'd have to go back to check which int corresponds to which game mode and that would just be prone to complications later on.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

All the bests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean with

> enums aren't really possible to select with MonoBehaviour-scripts

as MonoBehaviour certainly does support enums completely, and Unity even has a [tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enumerations?signup=true#5c8a6ee6edbc2a067d47537b) explaining their use within Unity.

Their usage is the same as descibed by [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class EnumUsage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum DifficultySettings { Easy, Medium, Hard, Extreme };
    public DifficultySettings difficultyInInspector; //This can be set from the editor

    private void Start()
    {
        SetGameDifficulty(DifficultySettings.Medium);
        SetGameDifficulty(1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass the difficulty directly as an enum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameDifficulty"></param>
    private void SetGameDifficulty(DifficultySettings gameDifficulty)
    {
        DifficultySettings difficulty = gameDifficulty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass the difficulty as an int and later cast it to enum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameDifficulty"></param>
    private void SetGameDifficulty(int gameDifficulty)
    {
        DifficultySettings difficulty = (DifficultySettings)gameDifficulty;
    }
}
```

Which can be set from the inspector like usual
[image]

Comment: Thank you for clearifying, Remy! I'm sorry I missed to mention, that it's during an OnClick event I want the enum-dropdown to appear. In other words, I have a Method that has a parameter that in this example would be the DifficultySetting-enum. Might that be possible? I can't seem to find the answer via Google - only that it's not possible.

Comment: @doingSomeSwiftHere Ah you mean like selecting an enum value from a dropdown menu inside a Button's OnClick event? Through the inspector only native types are supported (string, float, int, bool). What you could do is pass the `int` value of the enum value you want.